# Ambari cluster + what is the right syntax in order to upload blueprint json file to ambari cluster

Tags: json, hadoop, ambari, apiblueprint, blueprint

we have Ambari cluster **Version 2.5.0.3** , while all clients machines are Linux redhat

first I generated the json file to my Linux machine as the following: ( on ambari server machine )

```
 curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X GET -u admin:admin http://130.14.6.28:8080/api/v1/clusters/HDP01\?format\=blueprint > blueprint.json
```

then I update the blueprint.json file with some changes about the parameters and their values

finally my target is to upload the new blueprint.json to ambari cluster in order to take affect !

```
path=/root

curl -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" --data @ -X POST -u admin:admin http://130.14.6.28:8080/api/v1/blueprints/HDP01 -d @$path/blueprint.json
```

but I get the following errors ( seems because wrong syntax )

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "", this makes an empty POST. { 
"status" : 400, "message" : "Invalid Request: Malformed Request Body. An 
exception occurred parsing the request body: Unexpected character ('&' 
(code 38)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 
'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4a3484a6; line: 1, 
column: 3]"
```

please advice what is wrong in my syntax ?

And what is the right syntax in order to upload the new update **blueprint.json** file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to validate your JSON online e.g. at https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ ?
Looks like the problem is with general JSON syntax

Answer (score 0):

In curl command used to upload new bloueprint.json, you are using `--data @` as well as `-d @$path/blueprint.json`. `-d` and `--data` are used for same purpose hence first occurance i.e. `--data @` takes effect and command tried to locate file with no path i.e. `""`.

You may remove `--data @` to fix `Couldn't read data from file ""` error.